# Find the common ratio, if the sum of first 8 terms in GP(geometric progression) is 5 times the sum of first 4 terms also in GP.

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]

I tried it by supposing, (the supposition where “if the number of terms is odd, we take the middle term as ‘a’ and the common ratio as ‘r’. If the number of terms is even, we take ‘a\r’ and ‘ar’ as the middle terms and ‘r2 ‘as the common ratio.”
Sum of first 8 terms in GP,
S8 =  a/r7 + a/r5 + a/r3 + a/r + ar + ar3 + ar5+ ar7
S4 =  a/r3 + a/r + ar + ar3
by question,
S8 = 5S4 …………………………equ(1)
I tried solving equ(1) for r2
But still couldn’t find out the answer.
Please give it a try!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first term & the common ratio be $a,r\ne1$ respectively,

the [sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Derivation) of $n(\ge1)$ terms $$S_n=\frac{a(r^n-1)}{r-1}$$

So, $$5=\frac{S_8}{S_4}=\frac{r^8-1}{r^4-1}=r^4+1$$

Comment: i used the same formula for calculation. But i am confused on . Can i use the above supposition, and if then first term would be a/r7 and a/r3. and common ratio (r2) or i'm wrong. Considering the series.

Comment: @user124672, Where is your confusion?

Comment: considering first term in two different series.

Comment: @user124672, then the equation will be  $$\frac{\dfrac{a(r^8-1)}{r-1}}{\dfrac{A(R^4-1)}{R-1}}=5$$  Can you solve that even assuming $r=R$

Comment: i appreciate it. i understood.This question is solved with a basic supposition of series in GP, (a+ar+ar2+.....) But still the random supposition for GP numbers where (a/r,a,ar) and (a/r5,a/r3, a/r , ar , ar3 , ar5) are used still provokes my mind.

Answer (score 0):

We don't really need a formula, for 
$$a+ar+ar^2+ar^3+ar^4+ar^5+ar^6+ar^7=(a+ar+ar^2+ar^3)+r^4(a+ar+ar^2+ar^3).$$
Thus $1+r^4=5$.

Comment: wonderful process, its really helpful @ andre nicolas

Comment: The formula approach is a good one, the sum formula is pretty basic. But I wanted to use minimal machinery.